# How do I connect to a remote / external Phoenix app channel from another Phoenix app?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am looking to incrementally port over a legacy API application to Phoenix. Ideally, I would carve out the subdomains of my application into separate Phoenix apps and host them on different server nodes.

I am hoping to use Phoenix channels to facilitate app to app communication. How do I connect one Phoenix app to another's channels and topics? For example, I would like to set up a 'jobs.foo.com' subdomain with WebSockets like:

```
socket "/ws", Jobs do
   channel "jobs:work_orders", WorkOrdersChannel
end
```

From another Phoenix app (ex: Reports) I would like to pub/sub to that Jobs channel topic. Would it be advisable to create a `Phoenix.Endpoint` Jobs lib, in Reports, and configure that `Jobs.Endpoint` url in config.exs? Could I then make use of something like `Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe/4` with that named pubsub endpoint?

I am not sure if what I am thinking makes sense. If there is a more advisable approach, I am open to suggestion.

-- EDIT --

Just to clarify what I am trying to accomplish ... I am wanting to make one Phoenix app connect to another via a WebSocket client. That will allow me to have apps, with different domain logic, communicate via events over channels and topics of common interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a way to create WebSocket clients in my various Phoenix apps and allow app to app communication over remote channels and topics. I took my cues from:

[channel_test.exs](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/dd8db571843c0ac148ddc8f9504cfbf289856771/test/phoenix/integration/channel_test.exs)

and

[websocket_client.exs](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/dd8db571843c0ac148ddc8f9504cfbf289856771/test/phoenix/integration/websocket_client.exs)

I basically copied the `websocket_client.exs` code into my app's `../lib` directory, then loaded and alias'ed it. After that I could connect one app to the remote socket of another app, much like it is done in `channel_test.exs`. I spun up two separate Phoenix apps, on two different machines, and was able to send, and receive messages across the channels.

Don't forget to add `{:websocket_client, github: "jeremyong/websocket_client"}` to your `mix.exs` dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might want to look into [Phoenix.PubSub](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/0.9.0/Phoenix.PubSub.html) - as long as you manage to connect your nodes into a cluster (or even without that, using a DB or Redis backend) you should be able to make them talk to each other over that.

Comment: Something like RabbitMQ may be an option as well.

Comment: @pawel-obrok I've looked at Phoenix.PubSub for pointers. It's still not clear to me how I would go about making my Reports Phoenix app join / subscribe to the remote Jobs app "jobs:work_orders" channel as a client. I can connect my apps using Node.connect in a cluster, but that couples the different areas of concern more tightly than I was hoping. The JS client uses `new Socket("SOME_LOCATION").connect()` to establish a connection and then join a channel. I am looking for some sort of equivalent internal to Elixir / Phoenix.

Comment: `PubSub` is not used to subscribe to the existing channels. Rather it is a separate communication mechanism which has its own topics that you subscribe/publish to.